# Java class created for tag annotation in scalatest giving duplicate class error

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalatags

```
package com.mycompany.myproject.testing.tags;

import java.lang.annotation.*;
import org.scalatest.TagAnnotation

@TagAnnotation
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface DbTest {}
```

-- above created tag using java class is used on scalatest class
package com.mycompany.myproject.testing.tests

```
@com.mycompany.myproject.testing.tags.DbTest
class ValidationTest extends Funsuite with DFInput{
}
```

when running above scenario giving error below /D:/git/project/src/test/scala/com/mycompany/myproject/testing/tags/DbTest.java:[9,9] duplicate class: com.mycompany.myproject.testing.tags.DbTest

Comment: I had the same issue long ago, and I don't remember the EXACT solution, but the thing was that Intellij confused classpaths of main and test codes. so it tried to compile /src/main codes twice. try digging into your `project structure` tab.